# Is it correct to use MySQL set type?

Tags: sql, set

Hi
I am building a database of users where each user has some normal details stored about them.
I would also like to store which languages the user knows.

I know that one way to do this would be to create a language table and then create a separate table that maps between languages and users. Would it be easier to use the SQL "set" type instead of creating an extra table for languages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general rule, if you can enumerate all the possible/supported languages/values, `SET` will work.  Otherwise I'd use the table, because going back and `ALTER TABLE`ing to add a new language isn't a very good way to do things and will also probably require changes to the application(s) using the `SET`, whereas if you use a separate table it should Just Work to `INSERT` a new language row.

And, language being what it is, I'd not want to assume I know every language beforehand.

Comment: I didnt realize it would be an issue to add more languages but now it makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Probably not. There are lots of problems with using `SET` (only 64 elements, for example; and I'm pretty sure there are more than 64 languages).

Comment: The population Im dealing with only speaks about 20 languages so I wouldnt hit that limit.